# Stretch WebView

Tags: webview, xamarin.forms, stretch

I'm stuck on making a `gif` element which inherits from `WebView`. This "`WebView`" is representing the following html => `String.Format(@"<html><body><img src='{0}'/></body></html>", value);` where `value` is the URL to the GIF.

However, when I declare it with a local gif, it does work, but the focus of the webview is at the top/left. I can also move/scroll the view of the webview which overflows the limits of the screen..

**So, how can I make this WebView stretch about the screen?**

Comment: Add the xaml/cs of your `WebView`, that we see what you tried so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your WebView make sure you have the Horizontal and Vertical Options set to stretch it to the entire screen.

```
<WebView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

For your gif you will probably want the below to stretch your gif to the entire visible area.

```
<html><body><img src='{0}' style='width:100%;height:100%;'/></body></html>
```

If you want the WebView to only be the size of what inside it, then unless you want to get into some complicated javascript callbacks, I would just get the size of the gif and set the width and height request on the WebView.